# How to fix Notepad++ NppExec Error

Tags: python, notepad++, nppexec

I'm trying to fix a error in Notepad++, I'm using NppExec plugin in Notepad++ and trying to execute my code. Whenever I click Plugins, NppExec, Execute, a window popups. Then I type this:

```
print("Hello World")
```

and press 'OK', a error line like this appears:

```
print("Hello World!")
about to start a child process: "print("Hello World!")"
`CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:`  
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How should I fix this? Am I using it in the wrong way? Or is there any way to fix this? [Sorry if I hadn't explained well]

Comment: Is it saved as a file?

Comment: @Ollie The Python file (.py) is saved as a file at my Desktop

Comment: You might want to read the nppexec manual :). You cannot put Python commands into the nppexec Windows. You might want to do something like `npp_save` in one line and something like `<YOUTPATHTOYOUTRPYTHON.EXE>python.exe $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)`   in the second line. It saves your file and then runs the Python interpreter on it.